# How to create list using checkbox in Ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 and I want to use checkbox for the user to select which exam he/she is preparing. But I am unable to create this layout (UI). My exam list is coming from api.

[image]

When a user select any of the box the background color will change. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead, you can use ion-segment component to change the UI of the current page with binding that button's value to background color.

[As in docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#segment) you can manipulate like this for your sake. You can manipulate the UI according to your needs. Does that answer your question ?

```
 <div padding>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="examType">
    <ion-segment-button value="CPO">
      CPO
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="CHSL">
      CHSL
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="examType">
  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'CPO'">
   <div class="background-color-cpo"> </div>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'CHSL'">
    <div class="background-color-CHSL"> </div>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

Comment: The above image has only 8 exam list but i have almost 25-30 exam list.So how many ion-segment button will i use.I think it will become complicated.